# wordpress: How to add post index under single post in single.php

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, blogs

I have my main blog page that I have output all the post thumbnails and titles on for a navigation for my portfolio.

Here is the code that outputs the thumbnail gallery:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="mainpost">
                <div class="mainpostimage" style="background-image:url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()) ?>')"></div>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
        </a>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>



</div>
```

[And This is the live page](http://joshbutts.netne.net/testing-for-blog/).

I have the single.php file set up to output the post content but I want it to display the entire list of thumbnails underneath so the viewer can view the post and see basically the same thing as the blog index.php page. I copied the same code and placed it inside the wordpress while loop, but it only outputs the thumbnail for the current page.

Here is the code for my single.php page.

```
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-maina" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' ); ?>


<div class="morestuffhere">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="mainpost">
                    <div class="mainpostimage" style="background-image:url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()) ?>')"></div>
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
            </a>

</div>
         <?php the_post_navigation(); ?> 

        <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

        </main>
    </div>
```

This is a link to [sample post](http://joshbutts.netne.net/artschool/) page with only a thumbnail for the current post

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the setting and make your blog post page the front page or home page and your all post will be showing on the home page

Comment: There are a few problems with that. First, I don't want my blog page to be the front/home page, and the second problem, is that it doesn't solve my initial problem. On my single post page, there is still only the one link to the current post underneath.